# Datatables search mysql

Tags: jquery, mysql, search, datatables, inline-editing

I found this tutorial: [datatables example with mysql+php backend](http://www.script-tutorials.com/datatables-data-from-ajax-edit-in-place/), but when I tried to search columns on cyrillic, this JS popup appears:
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/KsLVt.png)
[image]

I don't understand how to use my own column names instead mysql column names.
How does one search with Cyrillic symbols? And how does one use names?

Function getMembersAjx in service.php print this json: `{"sEcho":0,"iTotalRecords":2,"iTotalDisplayRecords":2,"aaData":[{"0":"82","1":"1‌​5-07-13-WEB-580-B61","2":"2015-07-13 09:59:26","3":"345.00","4":null,"5":"Наличные","6":"Сейф","7":"Бараков В.Ф.","8":"123","DT_RowId":"82"},{"0":"83","1":"15-07-13-WEB-58B-F36","2":"2015-‌​07-13 10:05:13","3":"455.00","4":null,"5":"Веб-Касса (Теле2)","6":"Веб-Касса (Теле2)","7":"Бараков В.Ф.","8":"123","DT_RowId":"83"}]}`

CMySQL.php: pastebin.com/cy1n8EKr

Comment: i try to change this code:

`function updateMemberAjx()
{ $sVal = $GLOBALS['MySQL']->escape($_POST['value']); 

$iId = (int)$_POST['id']; 
if ($iId && $sVal !== FALSE) 
{ switch ($_POST['columnName']) { `

in service.php to use columnId without success

Comment: What is CMySQL.php? Need to see this.

Comment: This error is caused by datatables receiving invalid JSON. Can you post an example of the JSON you get back? The rest (column names, etc) is pretty easy after you get this first part figured out.

Comment: CMySQL.php:
http://pastebin.com/cy1n8EKr

Comment: Function `getMembersAjx` in service.php print this json:

{"sEcho":0,"iTotalRecords":2,"iTotalDisplayRecords":2,"aaData":[{"0":"82","1":"15-07-13-WEB-580-B61","2":"2015-07-13 09:59:26","3":"345.00","4":null,"5":"Наличные","6":"Сейф","7":"Бараков В.Ф.","8":"123","DT_RowId":"82"},{"0":"83","1":"15-07-13-WEB-58B-F36","2":"2015-07-13 10:05:13","3":"455.00","4":null,"5":"Веб-Касса (Теле2)","6":"Веб-Касса (Теле2)","7":"Бараков В.Ф.","8":"123","DT_RowId":"83"}]}

Comment: @smith_15  To add information, please [edit] your post rather than putting code into comments.